# Comparing data with Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of services and I need to list the times and that the same customer asked for the 3 types of service. (ServiceA, serviceB, serviceC)

In the low example I already got 2 service types but I tried to add a third one and I can not.

**Sorry for anything else that is very important and I forgot to mention is how did I even get the date that each service was done on that list?**

```
SELECT * 
FROM service 
WHERE status = 'CONCLUDED' AND (
   CASE WHEN service = 'servicoC' THEN 
   (CASE WHEN data LIKE '2017-05%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE data END) AND servico IN ' ServiceB ') 
GROUP BY id_client HAVING MIN (service) ='servicoA'AND MAX (service) ='servicoB'
```

Table:

```
Id;
Id client
service;
date;
Status;
```

Result Ex:

Id_client, date_serviceA, date_serviceB, date_serviceC

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Say ID 1 had services {A,B,C,D}, {A,B,C}, {A,B,E} all in 2017-05.  Would you want to see just the ID_Client once, or twice because services of A,B,C existed twice in 2017-05?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `GROUP_BY` and `HAVING`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id_client, COUNT(*)
FROM service
WHERE service IN ('ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC')
GROUP BY id_client
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT service)) >= 3;
```

If you want counts per service then you can add it into `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id_client, service, COUNT(*)
FROM service
WHERE service IN ('ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC')
GROUP BY id_client, service
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT service)) >= 3;
```

**Update**

If you want the max dates for each service then you can do so with inner `SELECT` queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.id_client, s.service, COUNT(s.*),
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM service where id_client = s.id_client and service = 'ServiceA') AS "date_ServiceA",
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM service where id_client = s.id_client and service = 'ServiceB') AS "date_ServiceB",
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM service where id_client = s.id_client and service = 'ServiceC') AS "date_ServiceC"
FROM service s
WHERE s.service IN ('ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC')
GROUP BY s.id_client, s.service
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.service)) >= 3;
```

Comment: I thought this at first as well; but it ask for the # of TIMES a customer had all 3 services; not the number of customers having all 3  services.  So all 3 have to be present for it to count I think. In which case I think I'd want some sort of row number partitioned by the client and service and find the count of the lowest # service of the 3.

Comment: @xQbert Same Here, That is why I ask for sample data and expected output. But maybe this is what OP want.

Comment: True; I guess I'll wait for clarification :P

Comment: @xQbert In case I need only the ID of this client that made the 3 types of service. If it had done 1 or 2 I do not want to list.

Comment: @BonfimJunior in which case, the above query would do the job. I have also added another query to get service level counts by the way..

Comment: @Darshan Mehta Thanks for the help, the code is perfect.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Sorry for anything else that is very important and I forgot to mention is how did I even get the date that each service was done on that list?

Comment: There can be multiple instances (rows) for each service. If you want min/max date then you can add `MIN(data)` or `MAX(data)` into `SELECT` fields.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Can you give me an example?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I need to display the date that each service was done in the listing

Comment: So, you don't want the count of services? Having both count of services and each service in the result is a bit illogical..?

Comment: @BonfimJunior can you add the sample output in the question?

Comment: @DarshanMehta Result Ex:

Id_client, date_serviceA, date_serviceB, date_serviceC